# Method to obtain a rand value bigger than value of system.currentTimeInMillis

Tags: java, random

How to generate a random value bigger than value of `System.currentTimeInMillis()`. I use `Random` object.how can I obtain a value that have min range as `System.currentTimeInMillis()`?

Comment: Get a random value... add the current time in ms to it... done

Comment: The method `System.currentTimeInMillis()` doesn't exist. Where did you get that? It should be `System.currentTimeMillis()` instead.

Comment: @EEP Possible overflows make it a little more complicated.

Answer (score 8):

Doesn't

```
long value = System.currentTimeMillis() + (long)random.nextInt(range);
```

work?

If you want to enforce a value that is strictly larger than `System.currentTimeMillis()` add an additional 1 to it. Set the range accordingly to prevent overflow (see `assylias`'s comment).

Edited according to comments.

Comment: nextInt() can be any `int` value (positive or negative or zero) Perhaps you meant `nextInt(range) + 1`

Comment: random.nextInt() could generate 0 value.how can I exclude 0 value?

Comment: Unless you define `range`, this can still overflow.

Comment: Checking for overflow is a little paranoid, unless you are worried about a year 292,278,994 bug. ;) I suspect Java will be dead by then. Never the less `Math.min(Long.MAX_VALUE, x)` doesn't do anything and is always `x`

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yes agreed - to be honest I'm not sure which version of the answer that comment was for ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This is an approach if you want to be able to get numbers distributed across the entire range `System.currentTimeMillis()..Long.MAX_VALUE`:

```
long millis = System.currentTimeMillis();    
long l = Math.min(Long.MAX_VALUE - millis, Math.abs(random.nextLong())) + millis;
```

Long.MAX_VALUE will be much more common than other results here though, in case that matters.

Answer (score 1):

For a uniform distribution of times between `currentTimeMillis` and `Long.MAX_VALUE`, **without overflow**, you can use:

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
long randomFutureTime = Math.abs(random.nextLong()) % (Long.MAX_VALUE - time) + time;
```

Answer (score 1):

This may is useful to have real time of object creation, and two objects cannot have the same timestamp, so you can order them.

I use as UUID for my objects :

```
Const.DECAL_BIT = 20;
Const.DECAL_BIT_MASQUE = (Long.size() -1) -  next 20;

private final Long timeCreate = (System.currentTimeMillis() << Const.DECAL_BIT) 
       + (System.nanoTime() & Const.DECAL_BIT_MASQUE);
```

So you can have valid dates for 100 years : you multiply by 1M the internal datetime and had one second elapse time in nanosecond precision.

To read the date : `Date d = Date((Long) timeCreate>> Const.DECAL_BIT);`